# How to trigger a click on checked radio button in jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Javascript:

```
if (GetCookie('prev_radio_value')!=null){   
     alert(GetCookie('prev_radio_value'));
     $(":radio[value="+GetCookie('prev_radio_value')+"]").attr('checked',true);
     $(":radio[value="+GetCookie('prev_radio_value')+"]").triggerHandler('click');

     $(':radio:checked').triggerHandler('click');

     $('input:radio[name=theme]:checked').click();

    }else{
        alert("clicking first");
     $("input:radio:first").attr("checked", true).trigger("click"); 
     }
```

HTML code:

```
<ul>
 <li><input type="radio"  name="theme" value="theme1"/>Theme1</li>
 <li><input type="radio"  name="theme" value="theme2"/>Theme2</li>
 </ul>
```

this code is inside div -> 'checkbox_div'

click function :

```
$("#checkbox_div input:radio").click(function() {
  alert("clicked") ;
 });
```

I have used the trigger click in 3 ways but none of them worked or triggered the click event.

example link : http://jsbin.com/ezesaw/1/edit is not triggering the click event upon selection of first radio button.

Comment: Change `attr()` to `prop()`, as the checked property should always be set with `prop()`, otherwise you'll have issues. Also, you should be using the `change` event on a radio button, not the `click` event, and use `input[type="radio"]` not `input:radio`.

Comment: Also, what you're looking for is `$('#checkbox_div input[type="radio"]:checked').trigger('click');`

Comment: $("input[type='radio' value="+GetCookie('prev_radio_value')+"]").prop('checked',true);   ...throws me an exception .... like this ..........Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [type='radio' value=theme1]

Comment: @adeneo its not working :(

Comment: What the heck is that supposed to be? You should read the jQuery documentation, you can't do it like that.

Comment: Old one, but: jsbin code doesn't work because it is triggering event before event handler is registered. Other than that, `:radio` selector is just fine, handler should be registered with `.on("click", ":radio", function(...` and `GetCookie()` call should be cached.

Answer (score 2):

Just call "click()" without the function as an argument

```
$("#checkbox_div input:radio").click();
```

Comment: This is not working ..... its not triggering the click event .... but how does it even know which radio button is clicked ... could you pls correct if am thinkin wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

It works just fine:

http://jsbin.com/ivojoz/1/edit

The problem may be that you are not selecting the radio correctly

try

```
$('#checkbox_div input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
  alert("clicked") ;
 });
```

Comment: this function works fine .... but i want to trigger the click event on a checked radio button ...upon document load....

Comment: click event is not triggered upon selection of first radio ...dono y .... [http://jsbin.com/ezesaw/1/edit](http://jsbin.com/ezesaw/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

In case u are still interested in this question:

The `click` event is implied when selecting/checking a radio button, all you need is to `bind` a procedure to it, this is just ONE way:

```
//js for radio button click
$('input[type="radio"]').on('click', function(){
    window.alert($(this).val());
})

<!--html-->
<input type="radio" value="first" name="same"/>
<input type="radio" value="second" name="same"/>
<input type="radio" value="third" name="same"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $("#checkbox_div").on('click','input:radio', function() {

      alert("clicked");

    });
```

Give this code a shot. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Whether done manually or programmatically, it seems that clicking an already checked radio button does *not necessarily* have any effect!

Assuming HTML of:

```
<input type="radio" name="rv_submit" value="delete" id="rb2" checked>
```

Trigger the required action via jQuery as follows:

```
$('#rb2').prop('checked', false);   // Turn off 'checked' ...
$('#rb2').click();                  // ... or click() has no effect
```